# Keyup not registering in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

My application is opens a 'tool palette' when you `ctrl+click`. When you release the `ctrl` key the tool palette should close. Strangely the tool palette does not close until you click somewhere outside of the palette. Once the palette loses focus it can register the `ctrl` key up event and close the palette. Even more strange is that after the first time, it works without having to click outside of the palette. Not sure whats going. Thanks in advance for any help.

[Heres a link to the codepen.](http://codepen.io/danielyaa5/pen/bprGWJ)

#### JS Code

```
var tp = document.getElementById('tool-palette');
var TP_STATE = 'CLOSED';
var tpH = null;
var tpW = null;

function showTp(x, y) {
  TP_STATE = 'OPENED';
  tp.style.opacity = 1;
  if (tpH === null || tpW === null) {
    tpH = tp.offsetHeight;
    tpW = tp.offsetWidth;
  }
  tp.style.left = x - tpW / 2 + 'px';
  tp.style.top = y - tpH / 2 + 'px';
}

function closeTp() {
  tp.style.opacity = 0;
  TP_STATE = 'CLOSED';
}

// open palette when ctrl + press
window.onmousedown = function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (TP_STATE === 'CLOSED') showTp(e.pageX, e.pageY);
  }
};

// close palette when alt key up occurs
window.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (TP_STATE === 'OPENED' && e.which === 17) {
    closeTp();
  }
}

// prevent the context menu from opening up 
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
  if (TP_STATE === 'OPENED') {
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}, false);
```

#### HTML

```
<ul class="menu" id="tool-palette">
  <li class="one">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="icon">icon-1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="two">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="icon">icon-2</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="three">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="icon">icon-3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="four">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="icon">icon-4</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="five">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="icon">icon-5</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="six">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="icon">icon-6</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="sector">
      <path fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" class="sector" d="M0.5,0.5 l0.5,0 A0.5,0.5 0 0,0 0.75,.066987298 z"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: I guess code for alt key is `18` so you should do `e.which === 18` in the statement for `keyup` function

Comment: sorry I meant `ctrl`. updated

Comment: Your codepen is working fine (using Firefox).